# parent class don't lock file with flock function

Tags: php

I've got a batch, which extends a base class.
I need to implement in base class a unique system execution, made with flock, so everyone extends from base class should have an unique execution

First class

```
class batch1 extends base_batch
{
    public function execute()
    {
        //do some stuff
    }
}
```

base class

```
abstract class base_batch
{
    private function realPathExecution()
    {
        $object = new ReflectionObject($this); 
        $location = $object->getFileName();
        return $location;
    }

    public function ensureOneExecution()
    {
        $realPath = $this->realPathExecution();
        $fp = fopen($realPath, "r+");
        if (!flock($fp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB, $blocked)) {
            if ($blocked) {
                // another process holds the lock
                print_r("Other sther script in run! \n");
                return False;
            }
            flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
            // couldn't lock for another reason, e.g. no such file
            print_r("Error! Nothing done. \n");
            return False;
        }
        return true;
    }


    public function __construct()
    {
        if (!$this->ensureOneExecution()) {
            print_r("Not flock!! \n");
            exit(1);
        }
        //do some stuff

        return;
    }

    ....


}
```

If I use this structure, I can execute 2 or more times simultaneously this code; but if I take outside ensureOneExecution function it works correctly.

Comment: Are you sure regarding the inheritance? `class batch1 extends base_batch` and `abstract class eBatch_Base` don't seem to fit together...

Comment: Yup, you're right, just a typo. I've just correct

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: When the method is left, the filepointer variable goes out-of-scope. File is closed, lock released.